# How can i use another url path as my cakephp folder structure

Tags: apache, cakephp

I want to use another url path for my cakephp 2 project as the standard folder path.

```
localhost
```

as

```
localhost/myproject
```

I want this to be my url path but not my folder path in my htdocs for example.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess you're trying to set virtual `host` for your project. In this case, using `localhost` won't be good idea (might be ambiguous). You can set virtual `host`. Follow the procedures:

***Step 1***

Open `httpd.conf` file located in `xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

Replace

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

With

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

***Step 2***

Create a `virtualhost` file. Open `httpd-vhosts.conf` file and add the following codes:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
DocumentRoot <PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_HERE>
ServerName <SERVER_NAME like local.example.com>
</VirtualHost>
```

***Step 3***

Open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add the below line at the end of file.

```
127.0.0.1      <SERVER_NAME like local.example.com>
```

***Step 4***

`Restart` apache server.